# Web services to validate the canadian address through purolator webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Hey I am trying to use Purolator  Web services to validate the address.

I already included web services in my project and have all  credential to communicate but I don't know how to validate through web services and it's my first time that I am using web services please help

I am using C#

I have three input field to asp.net to validate

- city
- Postcode and
- province

If someone can give me details info how to this validation through web service I will really appreciate their help.

Please give some sample code how can I do this

already included reference

```
using com.purolator.devwebservices;

  com.purolator.devwebservices.ValidateCityPostalCodeZipRequestContainer;
```

This is how it show in their documentation.

I like to upload the picture to show you the web service request and response diagram but I don't have privileges

```
ValidateCityPostalCodeZipRequestContainer

ValidateCity PostalCodeZipRequest

tns:RequestContainer (extension)

tns:Addresses SenderA ddress - ShortAddress[]

tns:ArrayOfShortAddress

tns:ShortAddress

tns:ShortAddress

tns:City City -string

tns:Province Province - string

tns:Country C ountry - string

tns:PostalCode P ostalC ode; - string
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to call the webservice, you first have to add a web reference, which you already did, now you need to instantiate the object of proxy class which from your post i believe is `ValidateCityPostalCodeZipRequestContainer` and call the `RequestContainer` method of object with required parameter to validate the address.

*** Answer above is based on my assumptions becuase I don't have any information about the webservice. If you can post `WSDL` then I can give a precise answer.

Between, according to Purolator's website there are number of sample available here: https://eship.purolator.com/SITE/en/content/developmentprocess/websservicesprogram.aspx
May be you can find one using asp.net

And by the way there is a nice tutorial given here for consuming webservices in asp.net: [Calling Web Service using ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/WebServiceConsumer.aspx).

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, I already watched that purolator tutirials but it doesnt help.  I tried to do by using your given codeproject link but I cant create my proxy object as It say index proxy is field and used as a datatype private com.purolator.devwebservices.ValidateCityPostalCodeZipRequestContainer proxy;
     proxy = new com.purolator.devwebservices.ValidateCityPostalCodeZipRequestContainer();
this is how i am trying to do

Comment: can you post the WSDL here? Between to get WSDL just browse add append ?WSDL to your webservice url